# How to programmatically add SOAP:Header to JAX-WS CXF client using variables from service?

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws

I'm attempting to call a SOAP backend (that I don't have access to) using a jaxws client with SOAP:Headers that are generated by a variable in the service (what I have access to).

Currently, I'm using an outbound interceptor that extends `org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor`. In the `handleMessage(SoapMessage)` method I correctly add SOAP:Headers that are added to the outbound SOAP request. This works with hardcoded values, but the values of the soap header could possibly change from request to request. Therefore, I need to be able to programmatically calculate the SOAP:Header on each outbound request to the jaxwsClient.

Jaxws client

```xml
<jaxws:client id="jaxwsClient"
                  address="https://SET_AT_RUNTIME"
                  serviceClass="wsdl.profileAccessPortType"
                  xmlns:svc="http://example.com/ProfileAccess_v12"
                  serviceName="svc:ProfileDelete"
                  endpointName="svc:ProfileDeletePort"
                  wsdlLocation="ProfileAccess_12.2.wsdl">
   <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false" />
            <entry key="org.apache.cxf.http.no_io_exceptions" value="true"/>
   </jaxws:properties>
   <!-- interceptor to inject client security token -->
   <jaxws:outInterceptors>
        <ref bean="ssv4OutboundInterceptor" />
   </jaxws:outInterceptors>
</jaxws:client>
```

WSDL

```xml
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:tns="http://example.com/ProfileAccess_v12"
                  xmlns:ama_2008_10_AMA_Profile="http://xml.amadeus.com/2008/10/AMA/Profile"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:addr="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
                  targetNamespace="http://example.com/ProfileAccess_v12"
                  name="ProfileAccess_12.2">
    <wsdl:documentation>Version 12.2</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema>
            <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/Profile"
                       schemaLocation="DeleteRQ.xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/Profile"
                       schemaLocation="DeleteRS.xsd"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="DeleteRQ_2.001">
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="prof:DeleteRQ"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="DeleteRS_2.001">
        <wsdl:part name="body" element="prof:DeleteRS"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="ProfileAccessPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="ProfileDelete">
            <wsdl:documentation>Version 12.2</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input name="DeleteRQ" message="tns:DeleteRQ_2.001"/>
            <wsdl:output name="DeleteRS" message="tns:DeleteRS_2.001"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="ProfileDeleteBinding" type="tns:ProfileAccessPortType">

        <soap:binding style="document"
                      transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="ProfileDelete">
            <soap:operation
                    soapAction="http://SET_AT_RUNTIME"
                    style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="DeleteRQ">
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="body"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="DeleteRS">
                <soap:body use="literal" parts="body"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="AirlineDelete">
        <wsdl:port name="ProfileDeletePort" binding="tns:ProfileDeleteBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://SET_AT_RUNTIME"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Is there a way that I can add something to the wsdl file that I'm using to add a SOAP header to the outbound request? Or is there a map that I can populate within the client that I can populate with the values that I can read within the AbstractSoapInterceptor?

An example of the values that I need to send to the backend are as follows:

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
      <Security xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <UsernameToken>
            <Username>**grab this value programmatically**</Username>
         </UsernameToken>
      </Security>
      <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">**grab this value programmatically**</Action>
      <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">bd986368-46dd-426b-a6bb-f6120ea2c962</MessageID>
      <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">**grab this value programmatically**</To>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <DeleteRQ xmlns="http://example.com/Profile" Version="12.2">
         <UniqueID ID="123" />
      </DeleteRQ>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add  Interceptors to your Endpoint that will add the required elements to the soap header.  For example, to programmatically add a UsernameToken to your soap header you can do something like this assuming you have generated Service and PortType classes from your WSDL...

```
MyService myService = new MyService();
MyPortTypeImpl myPort = myService.getMyPortType();

// set the webservice endpoint
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) myPort ;
bp.getRequestContext().put(
    BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
    "https://your.url"
);

// set up ws-security
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(myPort);
Endpoint endpoint = client.getEndpoint();
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
props.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
props.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, UTPasswordCallback.class.getName());
props.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "fred");
WSS4JOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(props);
endpoint.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);

// call the actual webservice
myPort.doSomething();
```

The UTPasswordCallback class populates the password value...

```
public class UTPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

  @Override
  public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
    for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
      WSPasswordCallback wpc = (WSPasswordCallback) callback;
      if (wpc.getIdentifier().equals("fred")) {
        wpc.setPassword("fredspassword");
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To add the ws-addressing soap header elements, you would add a `org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.MAPAggregator` out interceptor as well (see https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsaconfiguration.html).